# Android Java Programing Uri.parse(string) vs uri typed

Tags: android, parsing, media-player, uri

i have searched those topics, and i havent found any help.
I have this problem.
When i use something like MediaPlayer.

```
//This one is ok
mp.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.something);
mp.start();
//This one drives me crazy
String a="R.raw.something"
Uri uriss=Uri.parse(a);
mp.create(MainActivity.this,uriss);
mp.start();
```

It drops me error(1,-2147483648)
It is error for 
MediaPlayer error, this is not my error
Media file error, this is not my error
FilePath error, this could be my error but i dont understand why, and how can i solve this

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. Show us real, compiling code.

Answer (score 1):

The `R.java` class is auto-generated and contains other inner classes which represent the different resource types that are packaged with your app and each of those inner classes contain `static final int` fields which represent the resources.

Taking a basic example. The `/res/values/strings.xml` file in my project has a `String` for `app_name` which is "MyApp". In my `R.java` class, there is an inner class as follows...

```
public static final class string {

    // Various resource identifiers

    public static final int app_name=0x7f0a0038;

}
```

In other words, `R.string.app_name` isn't actually a `String` which represents "MyApp", it's a resource identifier which allows my code to find that `String` at runtime.

Trying to do `String a = "R.raw.something";` is basically trying to assign an `int` to a `String` but surrounding `R.raw.something` with "" won't work as `"R.raw.something"` is actually meaningless as a resource identifier.

The reason `mp.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.something);` works is because the `create(...)` method is taking an `int` as its second parameter and then uses it as a resource identifier to find the actual raw resource.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
String path1 = "android.resource://[your package name]/[res type]/[res id]"
Uri uri1 = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.music.sample/raw/myMusic");
```

Or

```
String path2 = "android.resource://[your package name]"
Uri uri2 = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.music.sample/" + R.raw.myMusic);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the `String` parameter to `Uri.parse` method should be an RFC 2396-compliant, encoded URI. Please refer to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#parse(java.lang.String). The error reported corresponds to `0x80000000` which is undefined error.

Answer (score -2):

"R.raw.something" doesn't look like a valid URI to me. You probably want

```
String a = R.raw.something;
```

and not

```
String a = "R.raw.something";
```